# The assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++

1. The assignment operator in C++ ( x= 5, for instance) returns a value, besides copying that value to the variable. What is the value returned by (that is. what is the result of ) the assignment operator?

Comment: hmm doesn't your question contain an answer? Assignment operator returns assigned value (for built-in types, for user-defined types it returns what user defined...)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the *built-in* copy assignment operator produces an lvalue expression, which can be assigned to. Effectively that is as if it were declared with a reference type result.

A user-defined copy assignment operator, for a class type, can have any return type, including (which IMO would be ideal) `void`.

However, if a class is to be used as item type of a standard container, then it's subject to the requirements of the standard library, and then the class' copy assignment operator must return a reference to the object assigned to.

**C++11 §17.6.3.1/2 (utility.arg.requirements/2), tables 22 & 23** (from N3290):

> **”** [image]

---

In order to declare a copy assignment operator as deleted or defaulted, it must return a reference to the assigned object's type, e.g.

```
struct S
{
    auto operator=( S const& ) -> S& = delete;
};
```

---

A user-defined copy assignment operator can only be defined for a class type, not for an enum type, because it's required to be a non-static member function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operator)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modiﬁable lvalue as their left
>   operand and **return an lvalue referring to the left operand**

and

> 2 In simple assignment (=), the value of the expression replaces that
>   of the object referred to by the left operand.

Thus if you the following code snippet

```
int x;
x = 5;
```

then x get the value 5 and the assignment expression returns the `lvalue` of x. This allows to combine assignment operators for example the following way

```
( x = 5 ) += y;
```

because expression `x = 5` returns lvalue of `x`.

In C this code will be invalid because in C the assignment expression returns `rvalue`.